# Is it forbidden to marry one's cousin in a special circumstance?

Tags: quran, hadith

Suppose, somebody touches his aunt/uncles's private parts with impure thoughts in mind. Later, after several years, that person becomes horribly ashamed, does repentance, and does [Tawba](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Repentance_in_Islam).

Would it be permissible for that person to marry his/her cousin ?

Please, give me some quotes from Koran or Hadith.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know all hadiths, but I am pretty sure you won't find anything about this specific case. The person was not supposed to touch his aunt ' s/uncle  private parts in the first place. It is like asking if you can eat a lamb rib after eating a pork rib and repenting, this case is only covered by the first interdiction.

Note that the responsibility of the person depends a lot of his / her age. It is possible that the uncle / aunt in question, due to his / her age, is more responsible.

Here is why the person should not marry his / her cousin :

- Consanguinity is bad for the health of the children. The oumma is big enough, the person can pick someone else.
- It will be very hard for the cousin to forgive this once found out
- It will be even harder for the cousin to forgive to his / her father / mother. Put yourself in the cousin 's shoes, the situation is just as bad.

If you know someone in this situation, tell him / her not to do it, I cannot picture this wedding going well.

Comment: I'm not sure what this answer is saying, but is this a fair summary: "it should be halal to marry your cousin, but here's three reasons why it might be a bad idea"?